# Is this how to unsubscribe from event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to unsubscribe from event when component is destroyed.

I am not sure that I am doing that in a proper way?

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  const claimNumber = 'T1339838'
  const {
    runtime
  } = this.context
  const data = await runtime.select('comments-get', {
    claimNumber: claimNumber
  })
  this.setState({
    commentsData: data
  })

  const commentsUpdated = runtime.fb.ref('/comments')
  commentsUpdated.on('value', childSnapshot => {
    this.updateComments(childSnapshot.val())
  })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  // TODO: Remove on listener
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.commentsUpdated)
}
```

Comment: `componentWillUnmount` is the correct place to unsubscribe from events/subscriptions - I don't quite understand why you're trying to remove an handler relating to comments from the `resize` event, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.removeEventListener should be used only when an event listener is added to the window object. For example, if you are adding an event listener by using the following code:

// Add a listener

```
window.addEventListener('resize', this.commentsUpdated);
```

Then, in componentWillUnmount, the event listener has to be removed with this code:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    // TODO: Remove on listener
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.commentsUpdated)
}
```

In the above case, just emptying or assigning null to this.commentsUpdated will do.